# Angular 4 Error upgrading package

Tags: angular, bootstrap-material-design

I have an angular 4 project, I have just upgrade the packages
after this I run the npm update command 
now I have this error when I try to serve the app:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'C:\app\node_modules\bootstrap-material-design\dist\js\material.min.js'

Before the update my package.json was this:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE.pdf",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/creativetimofficial/material-dashboard-pro-angular.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.4.0",
    "@angular/common": "4.3.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.3.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.3.6",
    "@angular/core": "4.3.6",
    "@angular/forms": "4.3.6",
    "@angular/http": "4.3.6",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.3.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.3.6",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.3.6",
    "@angular/router": "4.3.6",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^7.1.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^1.0.2",
    "angular2-material-datepicker": "^0.5.0",
    "animate.css": "3.5.2",
    "arrive": "2.3.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.5",
    "bootstrap-material-design": "^0.5.10",
    "bootstrap-notify": "3.1.3",
    "bootstrap-select": "1.12.2",
    "bootstrap-tagsinput": "0.7.1",
    "chartist": "0.9.4",
    "chartist-plugin-zoom": "0.4.0",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "datatables": "1.10.12",
    "datatables.net-bs": "1.10.12",
    "datatables.net-responsive": "2.1.1",
    "eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "4.17.47",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fullcalendar": "3.4.0",
    "googleapis": "19.0.0",
    "intl-tel-input": "^12.0.1",
    "jasny-bootstrap": "^3.1.3",
    "jquery": "1.12.4",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "moment-timezone": "0.4.0",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "^1.1.9",
    "ng2-nouislider": "1.6.1",
    "ng2-select": "^1.2.0",
    "ngx-chips": "^1.4.6",
    "nouislider": "9.2.0",
    "primeng": "^4.2.0-rc.1",
    "rxjs": "5.4.2",
    "twitter-bootstrap-wizard": "1.2.0",
    "typescript": "^2.3.4",
    "validate": "3.0.1",
    "web-animations-js": "2.2.2",
    "zone.js": "0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bootstrap": "3.3.32",
    "@types/chartist": "0.9.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/jquery": "1.10.31",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.73",
    "angular-ide": "^0.9.31",
    "codelyzer": "2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "3.2.0",
    "karma": "1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "2.0.0",
    "tslint": "4.5.0"
  }
}
```

I don't change any directory or something else
Than after the update the package.json is that:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE.pdf",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "...."
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.4.0",
    "@angular/common": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/core": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/forms": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/http": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/router": "4.4.4",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "angular2-material-datepicker": "^0.5.0",
    "animate.css": "3.5.2",
    "arrive": "2.4.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-material-design": "^4.0.0-beta.3",
    "bootstrap-notify": "3.1.3",
    "bootstrap-select": "1.12.4",
    "bootstrap-tagsinput": "0.7.1",
    "chartist": "0.11.0",
    "chartist-plugin-zoom": "0.4.1",
    "core-js": "2.5.1",
    "datatables": "1.10.13",
    "datatables.net-bs": "1.10.16",
    "datatables.net-responsive": "2.2.0",
    "eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "4.17.47",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fullcalendar": "3.5.1",
    "googleapis": "22.2.0",
    "intl-tel-input": "^12.0.1",
    "jasny-bootstrap": "^3.1.3",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "moment-timezone": "0.5.13",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "^1.1.9",
    "ng2-nouislider": "1.7.0",
    "ng2-select": "^1.2.0",
    "ngx-chips": "^1.4.6",
    "nouislider": "10.1.0",
    "primeng": "^4.2.0-rc.1",
    "rxjs": "5.4.3",
    "twitter-bootstrap-wizard": "1.2.0",
    "typescript": "^2.3.4",
    "validate": "3.0.1",
    "web-animations-js": "2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bootstrap": "3.3.36",
    "@types/chartist": "0.9.36",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.6.0",
    "@types/jquery": "3.2.13",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.32",
    "angular-ide": "^0.9.31",
    "codelyzer": "3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "3.3.0",
    "tslint": "5.7.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't know if it's related but I guess you'd want bootstrap 4 with bootstrap md 4

Comment: downgrading to "bootstrap-material-design": "^0.5.10" it seems to work, in the bootstrap-material-design 4.0.0 version there aren't some files in dist folder